# Is it possible to generate xsd from asmx

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services

I have a webservice provided by third party company , The web service return xml as string , like :

```
<string xmlns="http://www.BMS.co.il/">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 .....
```

Is there any possibility to generate XSD from asmx ? Then I can Create classes from this and not to parse those things manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XSD.Exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) will generate xsd and then you can use this to generate classes,

```
  xsd file.xml [/outputdir:directory]
```

*"If you specify an XML file (.xml extension), Xsd.exe infers a schema from the data in the file and produces an XSD schema. The output file has the same name as the XML file, but with the .xsd extension.
If you specify an XML schema file (.xsd extension), Xsd.exe generates source code for runtime objects that correspond to the XML schema."*

also,

If you have wsdl(you must have) then you can directly generate classes from it using [WSDL.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
     wsdl http://hostServer/WebserviceRoot/WebServiceName.asmx?WSDL
```